# Poem-writing and getting error for re-using the same function - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm doing this for a project. for which I need to do some web-scraping from Wikipedia specifically. This is the second phase of the project, so I need to create a poem about a person that the user enters (they have to have a Wikipedia page). I am using the Datamuse API for python to get some rhyming words which works really well.

Function ->

```
import requests

def get_10_rhyme_words(word):
    key = 'https://api.datamuse.com/words?rel_rhy=' 
    rhyme_words = []
    rhymes = requests.get(key + word)
    for i in rhymes.json()[0:10]:
        rhyme_words.append(i['word'])
    return rhyme_words
```

The criteria for the poem is that it needs to be at least 50 words long and make sense, so I came up with something like this:

> **“*firstName*” is nothing like “*nameWord1*”,**
>
> **but it sounds a lot like “*nameWord2*”.**
>
> **“*genderPronoun*” is a “*professionFinal*”,**
>
> **Which sounds a lot like “*professionWord1*”.**
>
> **“*genderPronoun*”’s favourite food might be waffles,**
>
> **But it might also be “*foodWord1*”.**
>
> **I now close this poem about the gorgeous “*firstName*”,**
>
> **By saying “*genderPronoun*”’s name sounds a lot like “*nameWord3*”.**
>
> ***professionFinal* was a variable used to describe their profession.**

It works well for the name, but I get an *IndexError* every time I run it for the profession.

Name ->
[The name poem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf2ne.png)

> Here is a short poem on Serena:
>
> Serena is nothing like hyena, but it sounds a lot like marina.

Profession ->
[The Profession Poem (Error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16LM1.png)

```
Here is a short poem on Serena:

Traceback (most recent call last):  File "main.py", line 153, in <module>    line4 = 'which sounds a lot like ' + random.choice(professionRhymes) + '.'  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 290, in choice    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

Here is the code I am using to make the poem ->

```
#Writing a poem about the person
firstName = person.split()[0]
foodWord = 'waffles'
print('\nHere is a short poem on {}:\n'.format(firstName))
nameRhymes = get_10_rhyme_words(firstName)
professionRhymes = get_10_rhyme_words(professionFinal)
foodRhymes = get_10_rhyme_words(foodWord)

if gender == 'Male':
  heOrShe = 'He'
else:
  heOrShe = 'She'

if gender == 'Male':
  himOrHer = 'Him'
else:
  himOrHer = 'Her'

line1 = firstName + ' is nothing like ' + random.choice(nameRhymes) + ','
line2 = 'but it sounds a lot like ' + random.choice(nameRhymes) + '.'
line3 = heOrShe + ' is a ' + professionFinal + ','
line4 = 'which sounds a lot like ' + random.choice(professionRhymes) + '.'
line5 = heOrShe + '\'s favourite food might be foodWord,'
line6 = 'but it might also be ' + random.choice(foodRhymes) + '.'
line7 = 'I now close this poem about the gorgeous {},'.format(firstName)
line8 = 'By saying {0}\'s name sounds a lot like {1}'.format(firstName, random.choice(nameRhymes))

print(line1)
print(line2)
print(line3)
print(line4)
print(line5)
print(line6)
print(line7)
print(line8)
```

**ignore the inconsistency and the lack of loops for printing each line

How do I make it so I don't get the error because frankly, I don't even know why I'm getting it...

Thanks!

(P.S.) Sorry for making it this long. Bye!

Comment: Well, it seems that the API is not returning you anything for whatever data you are giving it. What is the output if you did `print(professionRhymes)`?

Comment: It seems pretty clear that the function call `get_10_rhyme_words(professionFinal)` is returning an empty list.  Can you show us the code for that function?  Do you know how to use a debugger?  You should get into your debugger and step into the `get_10_rhyme_words` function for that call and see what it is doing and why it is returning an empty list.  You shouldn't have to ask others for help at this level.  This is an obvious error that we don't have enough information to answer, and you should be able to easily track this down on your own.

Comment: Where does `professionFinal` come from? What happens if you use the website manually to look up rhymes for that profession?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone that responded. It seems the consensus was enough to make me print the list and see that it comes up empty. Sadly, I am using repl and it doesn't have a debugger. But thanks guys, I found out the problem and will alter my poem to suit the needs of the program. As for the people asking the code, I only needed to check if their profession was that of a scientist, sportsperson, or politician. So I made a list, made a for loop check for keywords related to professions, then picked the right one. That is what professionFinal was.

Code:

```
#Finding their profession
#Declaring keywords for each profession
sportspersonKeywords = ['Sportsperson', 'Sportsman', 'Sportsman', 'Sports', 'Sport', 'Coach', 'Game', 'Olympics', 'Paralympics', 'Medal', 'Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Player', 'sportsperson', 'sportsman', 'sportsman', 'sports', 'sport', 'coach', 'game', 'olympics', 'paralympics', 'medal', 'bronze', 'silver', 'gold', 'player', 'footballer', 'Footballer']

scientistKeywords = ['Scientist', 'Mathematician', 'Chemistry', 'Biology', 'Physics', 'Nobel Prize', 'Invention', 'Discovery', 'Invented', 'Discovered', 'science', 'scientist', 'mathematician', 'chemistry', 'biology', 'physics', 'nobel prize', 'invention', 'discovery', 'invented', 'discovered', 'science', 'Physicist', 'physicist', 'chemist', 'Chemist', 'Biologist', 'biologist']

politicianKeywords = ['Politician', 'Politics', 'Election', 'President', 'Vice-President', 'Vice President', 'Senate', 'Senator', 'Representative', 'Democracy', 'politician', 'politics', 'election', 'president', 'vice-president', 'vice president', 'senate', 'senator', 'representative', 'democracy']

#Declaring the first sentence (from the summary)
firstSentence = summary.split('.')[0]

profession = ['Scientist', 'Sportsperson', 'Politician']
professionFinal = ''

#Splitting the first sentence of the summary into separate words
firstSentenceList = firstSentence.split()

#Checking each word in the first sentence against the keywords in each profession to try to get a match
for i in firstSentenceList:
  if i in sportspersonKeywords:
    professionFinal = profession[1]
    break
  elif i in scientistKeywords:
    professionFinal = profession[0]
    break
  elif i in politicianKeywords:
    professionFinal = profession[2]
    break

#if a match is found, then that person has that profession, if not, then their profession is not in our parameters
if professionFinal == '':
  print('[PROFESSION]: NOT A SPORTPERSON, SCIENTIST, OR POLITICIAN')
else:
  print('[PROFESSION]: ' + professionFinal)
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You should add a check for what the request returns. If it returns an empty list, it cannot be used as a `random.choice()` argument, since it requires a list with one or more item.

This part of this error

```
line4 = 'which sounds a lot like ' + random.choice(professionRhymes) + '.'
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py",
line 290, in choice
raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')
from None IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

`professionRhymes` is probably returning an empty list.

Comment: Yup. Thanks! I made it print each variable and professionRhymes was returning empty because I only have to pick from three professions: scientist, sportsperson, or politician. Serena Williams is a sportsperson, and there is no word that rhymes with sportsperson, so the list was empty. I'll just have to change my poem to suit this, but thank you very much for your suggestion.